# How to free the ROM memory allocated to Ubuntu installed on Virtual Box?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, partitioning, rom

I installed Ubuntu on Oracle VM Virtual box. I choose 34GB ROM(fixed memory) memory and 4GB RAM memory while installing.

Now I am unable to open Virtual box due to missing .msi file. So I uninstalled Oracle VM Virtual box.

But memory allocated while installing is not freed. How do I retrieve that memory.

Every time I install windows drive memory will reduce and old memory is never restored back.

How to free memory?

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not the correct place for your question - programming questions only.

Answer (score 0):

To free the ROM memory(fixed or Flexible) you need to delete the **Ubuntu.vdi** file from your system. This will free the disc space.

After doing lot of search I found folder where "Ubuntu.vdi" is located.

[image: Ubuntu.vdi file location on my PC]

I hope on all windows system Ubuntu.vdi file will be same location. Just delete the **VirtualBox VMs** folder before you re install it.